# Populate DropDown based on Previous DropDown

Tags: php, javascript

Currently I have a setup along these lines http://jsfiddle.net/4Zw3M/1/ where the second drop down is populated by a previous selection.

The problem is that the fields are populated by a database. So as PHP I would write the option dropdown as this to retain the value after submitting.

```
<option <?= $foobar == $foo->slug ? 'value="'.$foo->slug.'" selected="selected"' : 'value="'.$food->slug.'"'?>><?=$foo->name?></option>
```

I can't figure out how to retain the value after a user submits the form. Also yes I do have `$foobar = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['foobar']);` at the top of the page to caputre the value.

Secondly I am trying to figure out how to add the value in this format as the value is actually the id of the name.

```
|id| |name  |
|1 | |ten   |
|2 | |twenty|
```

So in normal formatting it would be

```
<option value="<?=$foo->id?>"><?=$foo->name?></option>
```

Currently I can only make the value be the same as the name.

Comment: The form postback is to the form page, and you are asking how to take the selected dropdown data on submission and persist it back to the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post the dropdown menu text to the action page and capture the value using:-

```
    $s_option = $_POST["somename"];
```

Depending on the value of selected text($s_option) invoke JS functions like this:-

```
function func1()
{
document.forms[0].somename.selectedIndex=0;
}

function func2()

{
document.forms[0].somename.selectedIndex=1;
}
```

and so on......

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it in jquery/ajax/php, hope this helps:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#dropdown1').on('change', function(){
            var value = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "path_to_your.php",
                data: ({p : value}),
                datatype: "json",
                success: function(results){
                    $.each(results, function(v) {
                        $('#dropdown2').append($('<option>', {
                            value: v,
                            text: v
                        }));
                     });
                }

            });
        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="dropdown1">
    <option>Select One..</option>
    <option value="something">Something</option>
<select>
<select id="dropdown2">

</select>
</body>
```